# PDF 417 Detection and Decoding

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, barcode, zxing

Are there any **free** alternatives to Zxing's PDF 417 barcode detector and decoder?

The following 2 iOS libraries cannot seem to scan these type of bar codes, even though they say it's supported:

- https://github.com/zxing/zxing
- https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC/

I've read on Zxing's SVN/Google Code page that PDF 417 decoding is in the **alpha** stage, which probably explains why my the barcodes I'm testing on aren't being recognized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few days of research and testing, I've come across the following, effective, yet non-free solutions:

- [RedLaser's SDK](http://redlaser.com/developers/)
- [Manatee Works' SDK](http://manateeworks.com/)

Answer (score 1):

With iOS7 or above, you don't have to rely on third-party libraries for barcode detection or decoding. [AVFoundation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVFoundationFramework/index.html) has built-in (and hence free) support for detecting both 1D and 2D barcodes including PDF417 and QR codes using the device camera.

You can find working examples [here](http://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/torrey-betts/archive/2013/10/10/scanning-barcodes-with-ios-7-objective-c.aspx) and [here](https://www.shinobicontrols.com/blog/posts/2013/10/11/ios7-day-by-day-day-16-decoding-qr-codes-with-avfoundation).

Comment: This question was posted before iOS 7 was released. Also, the 2D barcode scanners that iOS are not calibrated to scan all real-world credentials. Here's an article that I wrote regarding real-world tests of the 2D iOS 7 scanner: https://medium.com/arthurs-coding-tips/apples-native-ios-barcode-scanner-is-junk-83d2129bd017

Comment: That's interesting.. one of the primary reasons for us to ditch ZBar and go for AVFoundation is [Apple's restriction to use 64-bit architecture](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=12172014b). Why should we mess with compiling third party libraries for 64-bit architectures when we have built-in way for scanning barcodes? So far, I haven't faced significant issues with AVFoundation; it seems to be fast and is able to instantly recognize driver licenses (PDF417) and 1D barcodes from receipts (even distorted ones). We have iPod touch 5th generation and iPhone 5S devices with iOS 8.3.

Comment: You were able to get AVFoundation to recognize driver's licenses? What states worked for you? I had issues with multiple states, so I switched to a different third-party framework.

Comment: It's working flawlessly for GA, LV and ID. Anyway, testing for more states will be happening eventually as the application rolls out to production.